# Assignment and logical AND

Tags: php

What happens to Y value? I understand "assignment" operator has higher precedence than "and" logical operator. But what happens to (And false).

Thanks

```
<?php 
$x = true and false;   //$x will be true
$y = (true and false); //$y will be false

echo "x " .$x; 
echo "y" .$y;
```

I am seeing this.

```
x 1
y
```

Comment: Thank you Phillip. PHP is so strange. If the value is False , it is somehow  not assigned to a variable. It is a first time, I heard something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First line:

```
($x = true) and false;   //$x will be true
```

The result of `true` is obviously `true`, so `true` is assigned to `$x`. The second expression after `and` is also executed, because `true` is `true`, but the result of `false` (which is false) is never assigned to something.

```
$y = (true and false);   //$y will be false
```

In this case, there are parenthesis around the expression says, that the result of whole expression should be assigned to `$y`. As `true` is `true`, the second expression is also evaluted (like in the first one). But the result of the whole expression is `false`, because the second expression is `false`.

Example from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
// The constant true is assigned to $h before the "and" operation occurs
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

Comment: How assignment executes first while the logical `and` has higher precedence over assignment?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @Siraj `&&` has an higher precendence as `=`, but not `and`. Same is valid for `or`